# Importing CSS helper function that uses 'document' in NextJS

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I am using styled-components. I'd like to import a function that helps create fluid styles. My function uses the following:

```
const root = document.querySelector('html');
const pixelsPerRem = Number(getComputedStyle(root).fontSize.slice(0, -2));
```

When I import my function using

```
`const clampBuilder = dynamic(() => import('utils/clampBuilder'), {
 ssr: false,
});`
```

I see `clampBuilder is not a function`. I understand that since NextJS is SSR, there is no `document`. I am wondering how I could import my helper function or somehow use it to calculate what I need.

Function gist: https://gist.github.com/RockinRonE/b163549f684c1b4841941a6054888602

Answer (score 0):

Above error says that your `clampBuilder is not a function` and it doesnt seems to be any issue with SSR or with document.

can you try updating dynamic import as following:

```
const clampBuilder = dynamic(import('utils/clampBuilder'), { ssr: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the two lines shown above from the function and set `pixelsPerRem` to 16 since that's the default for most browsers. It may not be perfect, but it is good enough!